# doctrine2 slow too much querys

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm

I saw that my query is going to slow, the case is, that doctrine is doing over 6000 queries to complete this on, how i can solve it? to do in single query ?

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->leftJoin('u.ratings','r','WITH','r.user=:user');
    $qb->where('r.id is NULL and u.deleted !=1 and u.type != 5 and u.user!=:user')
    ->setParameter('user',$user);

    return $qb->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
```

Comment: Please clarify, you run that query over 6000 times?

Comment: only once, and doctrine makes 6000 requests to server...

Comment: the problem is i think joins or something like that because i guess it works like this "first selects all u, than for each u selects u.ratings"

Answer (score 0):

ok found the bug.. `'r.user=:user'` user is entity, and it lazy loads every time it so i need to leftjoin user too and check by id.